# Batch array variables into new subtracted array

Tags: batch-file

I have variables in array pnn1, pnn2, pnn3 etc and count, number of variables.
I want to store into new variables vpnn1, vpnn2 etc from 9th to 50th character.

```
::::::::::::     works fine
for /L %%b in (1,1,%count%) do (
    echo  !pnn%%b:~9,50! 
)
::::::::::::    does not work
for /L %%a in (1,1,%count%) do (
    set "!vpnn%%a!=!%pnn%%a:~9,50!"
)
```

It must be in variables, I use them later.

Comment: `set !vpnn%%a!=` tries to set a variable that is contained in a variable named `vpn<n>`, better to use `set vpnn%%a=`. In `!%pnn%%a:~9,50!` the first percent seems to be wrong